# Spring Batch reader file by file

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-batch

I'm developing a Spring webapp, using spring boot and spring batch frameworks.

We have a set of complex & different json files, and we need to:

1. read each file
2. slightly modify its content
3. finally store them in mongodb.

The question: It makes sense to use [spring batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) for this task? As I can see in tutorials examples etc, spring batch is the right tool for line by line processing, but what about file by file?

I don't have problems with the writer ([MongoItemWritter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemWriter.html)) and processer, but I do not see how to implement the reader.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**yes** you can definetly use Spring Batch. 
The item for your Reader can be a  `File`.

```
 public class CustomItemReader implements InitializingBean{

    private List<File> yourFiles= null;

    public File read() {
        if ((yourFiles!= null) && (yourFiles.size() != 0)) {
            return yourFiles.remove(0);
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Reading Items from Service
    private void reloadItems() {
        this.yourItems= new ArrayList<File>();
       // populate the items
     }


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        reloadItems();
    }
}
```

A custom Processor :

```
public class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<File, File> {
@Override
public File process(File arg0) throws Exception {
   // Apply any logic to your File before transferring it to the writer
 return arg0;
 }
}
```

And A custom Writer :

```
  public class MyWriter{
      public void write(File file) throws IOException {
         }
   }
```